# Numpy's logic functions and the "if cond is False" idiom

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

When applying PEP8's "if cond is False" idiom proposed by PyCharm with [numpy's logic functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html) such as `np.isinf` or `np.isnan`, we get surprising behaviors.

```
>>> import numpy as np
... assert not np.isnan(0), "first test failed"
... assert np.isnan(0) is False, "second test failed"
AssertionError: second test failed
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that numpy's logic functions do not return a `bool`, but an instance of `numpy.bool_`, which is a different type. Thus,

```
>>> np.bool_(False) is False
False
```

One could think of using the `dtype` argument of those functions to force a `bool` output, but this won't work.

```
>>> type(np.isnan(0, dtype=bool))
numpy.bool_
```

A solution is to cast explicitely to bool:

```
>>> bool(np.isnan(0)) is False
True
```

Even better: never use the `if cond is False` idiom which can break when `cond` is not a boolean. Simply use `not cond`:

```
>>> not np.isnan(0)
True
```

Actually, I didn't find a recommandation for the `if cond is False` idiom in PEP8; [it even says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

```
Yes:   if greeting:
No:    if greeting == True:
Worse: if greeting is True:
```

I don't know why this idiom is proposed by PyCharm. Don't use it, I have been bitten by it and there is no reason you should too.